# Prove this sequence converge to 0.5?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

prove that,
as k -> infinity
$$\sqrt k  \cdot \sqrt {k + 1}  - k \leqslant 0.5$$

---

I tried following
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \left( {\sqrt k  \cdot \sqrt {k + 1}  - k} \right) = 0.5$$
$$\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\exists N > 0{\text{ st}}{\text{. }}\left( {N < k < \infty } \right) \to \left( {\left| {\sqrt k  \cdot \sqrt {k + 1}  - k - 0.5} \right| < \varepsilon } \right){\text{ }}$$

How to choose N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{k(k+1)} - k & = \frac{k(k+1) - k^{2}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)} + k}\\\\
& = \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^{2} + k} + k}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{k}} + 1}
\end{align*}

Now you can apply the continuity of the square root function. Can you take it from here?

Comment: So I started with $0.5 - \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{k}}  + 1}}} \right) < \varepsilon $, 
and I got $N = \frac{1}{{{{\left( {\frac{1}{{0.5 - \varepsilon }} - 1} \right)}^2} - 1}} < k$. 
Is this correct?